# Setting a cell equal to another cell using a formula

Tags: excel

Hopefully the title doesn't throw everyone off too much as I am having a real hard time explaining this without an example.

What I am trying to find out is if the following logic is possible in Excel.

1. in cell A1 I have the value 12/14/2016
2. in cell B1 I have the value 12/15/2016
3. The pattern continues forwards and backwards for the dates
4. In cell A3 I want to have the value of whatever cell houses the current day (IE. today A3 should equal "A1" and not "12/14/2016")

I am currently running through some iterations of IF statements to see if I can get anywhere but have not made any actual progress on this.

Thoughts?

Comment: `=TODAY()` would work probably

Comment: That would give me the date itself as opposed to the cell the date presides in

Comment: Sorry, I've misread your question. Try `=CHAR(64+MATCH(TODAY(),1:1,1))&"1"`

Comment: Is this the end result or are you going to use this in another formula?  If it is not the end result then explain and give more detail and we can help skip this step.

Comment: This would be the end result, the range on my sheet would be different but that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With values in row 1 `(1:1)` this will give you the address of the cell with today's date.

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(1:1,MATCH(TODAY(),1:1,0))),COLUMN(INDEX(1:1,MATCH(TODAY(),1:1,0))))
```

or just

```
=ADDRESS(1,MATCH(TODAY(),1:1,0))
```

**Note**

The addition of `,4` will return a relative reference

```
=ADDRESS(1,MATCH(TODAY(),1:1,0),4)
```